# PhoneGap & jQuery Mobile: Script does not load

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I spend my day in front of the following problem. I tried to get PhoneGap and jQuery-mobile running. The app starts but, if I submit the form he loads the same site again, ignoring everything in the form.js (see below the html-code).
I have this html-Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>SecureBook</title>
</head>
<body onload="app.initialize();">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="userdata">
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"  autofocus>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Passoword">
                <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" data-icon="forward" data-theme="b">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            gotLoaded();
            console.log("in HTML");
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

It seems like he doesn't load the form.js as he isn't calling the function gotLoaded() nor console.logging anything. The form.js looks as like that:

```
function gotLoaded(){
console.log("loaded form");
};
$('#userdata').submit(function(event){
    console.log("transmitted form");
    event.preventDefault();
    var user = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.mobile.changePage("sites/contacts.html",{
        transition: "none"
    });
});
```

He does however load all the other scripts out of the js-folder, but isn't executing anything from the form.js. At least not on my Android-phone, in the Browser he is showing me the things I log. I hope you might be able to help me.
Thanks a lot,
stiller_leser

P.S. Just saw that he isn't logging ("transmitted form") either.

Comment: If it is not a problem for you, zip your code and send it to ma email, I will fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, works for me as shown below. Not a nice solution, but it works. The answer to the "Why" is welcome though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by adding the submit event handler in a pageshow handler(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/api/events.html) in the head, but you also need to give your page an id.

```
<script>
    $('#pageID').live("pageshow", function() {
        $('#userdata').submit(function(event){
            console.log("transmitted form");
            event.preventDefault();
            var user = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            $.mobile.changePage("sites/contacts.html",{
                transition: "none"
            });
        });
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me as shown below. Got no idea why though. Seems like adding my form script at the end makes sure that all jQuery-Stuff is loaded. Here's the final code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>       
    <title>SecureBook</title>
</head>
<body onload="app.initialize();">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="userdata" onsubmit="gotLoaded();">
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"  autofocus>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Passoword">
                <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" data-icon="forward" data-theme="b">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            //WORKS
            console.log("in HTML");
            //JQUERY works here
            console.log($('title').html());
        </script>
    </div>

<!-- Put customs scripts here as it seems, that jQuery loads to slow in the head and scripts already run -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
</body>
```